# Incompatible cv-qualifiers with template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I have a constructor that accepts a pointer-to-member-function. I have two different functions to be passed in but they fail with some variation of `incompatible cv-qualifiers`.

The constructor parameter is

```cpp
constructor(T (Class::* memfnptr)())
```

where `T` and `Class` are typenames.

My two member functions are of the following types when passed as arguments.

```cpp
long int (Encoder::*)() const
const char* (Drivebase::*)()
```

I have tried many combinations of const qualifiers in the following positions, plus a reference `const V (Class::* const func)() const`, `const V (Class::* const & func)() const`.

I can get either one of my functions to work, but not both. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to write more than one constructor, each matching one of the different syntaxes.

Comment: Think of `long int (Encoder::*)() const` as looking like `long int (*)(const Encoder *)` and `const char* (Drivebase::*)()` looking like `const char* (*)(Drivebase *)` and you won't be too far off. The parameters don't line up right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot deduce the `const`-qualifier of the member function pointer in template argument deduction, so you need two overloads:

```
template<typename T, typename Class>
constructor(T (Class::* memfnptr)());

template<typename T, typename Class>
constructor(T (Class::* memfnptr)() const);
```

The first one will be called for member functions which are not `const` qualified and the second will be called for those that are.

Note that there are more qualifiers for member functions with the same problem: `volatile`, `&` and `&&`

You may not need to accept all of these since they are uncommon, but to get a full set you need 12 overloads.

Comment: Note that if the constructor stores the function pointer, for example the `constructor` class has a `T (Class::* m_memfnptr)();` member, you're in for similar hell.

Comment: Why doesn't passing a non-const into the const overload work? It works for parameters or variables.

Comment: The `const` is part of the function type. You cannot store a function taking a `const` parameter in a function pointer taking a non-`const` parameter either (at least not without explicit cast, but then calling the function through that pointer would be UB). The issue here is that you can deduce the `const` on return type and parameter as is done in the shown code, but the language simply lacks a syntax to deduce the const-qualifier (since it isn't really part of `Class`). I don't think anyone is happy about that and if I remember correctly there are proposals to fix this.